# Why Yii logout users when DB Schema updated or model updated

Tags: yii

Whenever i do some changes in database schema(add/drop columns in a table) and accordingly update the model, Yii logs me out on any subsequent call to a url that may or may not involve that model. Is there any other proper way to update the production site, so that users currently using the application don't get affected(logged out).